# 2 Connection Strings, The Security String Works, The Entity Framework One Doesn't

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I'm new to ASP.NET and finding connection strings very difficult to get to grips with.

I've been half successful with my connection of the 2 connection strings below, the connection string for the database security works fine, but I’m unable to get the main string dealing with the rest of the data to work. I think it must be because of the Entity Framework element of the connection string.

For the metadata part, I've used the `res://*/` part as I assume this is less efficient but will catch all, if I've correctly understood the documents that I've been reading.

```
<remove name="ApplicationServices" />
  <add name="ApplicationServices" 
     connectionString= "Server=184.168.194.64,1433;
     Database= myASPNETDB;
     User=****;
     Password=****;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

 <remove name="PropManEntities" />
    <add name="PropManEntities" 
         connectionString="Metadata=res://*/;
                 provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
                 provider connection string='Data Source=184.168.194.64,1433;
         Initial Catalog=myTest_C;
                 User=****;
                 Password=****;
         multipleactiveresultsets=true'" 
                 providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I get the following error when I open a page with data:

```
The query syntax is not valid. Near line 6, column 17.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.EntitySqlException: The query syntax is not valid. Near line 6, column 17.

Source Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 

[EntitySqlException: The query syntax is not valid. Near line 6, column 17.]
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.EntityDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +964
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +21
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +138
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +30
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsView.DataBind() +4
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +105
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsView.EnsureDataBound() +223
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls()+75
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +83
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +974
```

GoDaddy are unwilling to provide any assistance with this matter.

*Edit:*

After attempting Matteo's suggestion I got the following error:

```
The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[ArgumentException: The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.]
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString) +8425830
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection..ctor(String connectionString) +43
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateEntityConnection(String connectionString) +85
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(String connectionString) +12
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.EntityDataSourceView.ConstructContext() +461
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.EntityDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +102
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +21
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +138
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +30
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsView.DataBind() +4
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +105
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsView.EnsureDataBound() +223
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls()+75
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +83
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)+974
```

Comment: Are you using Code first or generating an .edmx from a database?

Comment: I don't think the Metadata=res://*/ is working and if it is, don't think this is really handy, because it will cause issues if you use multiple, e.g. Models from other assemblies. Try setting the correct .csdl, .ssdl and .msl (if you don't know what it has to be, re-add an edmx and let it create the connectionstring for you).

Comment: am I reading this right, that you have data in two separate databases?

Comment: @Claies Yes, that's right, one for the aspnetdb database that deals with the security and one for the main database. I didn't know if I could combine the two.

Comment: @MrBliz i have generated an .edmx from a database.

Comment: Have you tried @Dacker's Advice? The Metadata part of connection looks wonky. If you're using an edmx then you'll need the .cdsl, ssdl etc.

Comment: @MrBliz yes I've tried Dacker's advice, I still got the same error message. I tried the following Metadata line which was automatically generated by ASP.NET: **metadata=res://*/DAL.PropTest.csdl|res://*/DAL.PropTest.ssdl|res://*/DAL.PropTest.msl;  **

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<add name="PropManEntities" connectionString="data source=184.168.194.64,1433;initial catalog=myTest_C;User Id=****;Password=****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Sorry, I didn't realize you're using edmx file..
try this version (instead of the ????? use your filenames) :

```
<add name="PropManEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/??????????.csdl|res://*/????????????.ssdl|res://*/???????????????.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=184.168.194.64,1433;initial catalog=MPInvoicingSystem;user id=*****;password=*****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

If this is not working, I'd suggest you to add a new edmx model and copy the connection string automatically added.
Matteo

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, please see the edited question for the new error message that I received when I tried it. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Matteo I’ve been trying to understand the .csdl, .ssdl and .msl files element of the connection string. I’m under the impression that these are contained in the .edmx file. However, when I compile my project, I’ve noticed that my DAL directory which contains the .edmx file is not one of compiled elements. Do I need to try and create these files, or do I need to change the connection string?